# Merging .flv chunks from stream site

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg, rtmp, flv

I'm trying to download a video from an alternative version of the Ustream site.  This site is apparently used for a DRM protection, in fact you can't watch this video without having access to it through a login from this site. 
The video system should be the same used by ustream (same links), that is calling different flv chunks every x seconds and merging them into the stream (similar to an rtmp service, but it doesn't use this protocol).

I managed to download every .flv chunks composing this video, but i had issues on merging them into a single file. First of all these flvs files have some audio/video lags/problems, but since there is no other way to download this video i'm not complaining about lags.

The real issue is that every flv file has an additive increase on the duration, despite having a normal size. Video duration is about 6 seconds, so the first chunk is 6 seconds long, the second chunk is 12 seconds long, although only the first 6 are visible (the remaining 6 are "corrupted"). If i try to merge (with ffmpeg or any video-joining software) all these files  (about 600-700, for a total duration of 1 hour and 15 minutes) only the first two sections are visible, then I cannot see anything. (Being more clear, if i try to merge the first 2 chunks, file is 18 seconds long and i can see the first 12; if i try to merge the first 3 chunks, file is 36 seconds long and i can still only see the first 12 seconds.)

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Well, i don't know if you did read the question but there's no code to show. What i asked was a method to merge flv chunks in a similar/identical environment (where every following chunk bring the duration of the preceding ones). The merging command is the default one. My issue is about getting the real duration of the chunks. I thought something about trimming every .flv file but there are 700 files and i have to trim one hour minus 6 seconds in the last ones.

Comment: @Iztooi at least show us your ffmpeg "merge" command. Maybe it's used incorrectly, like how do you merge just 2 or 3 flv for example? Got a link to two example consecutive chunks? Need to check if each chunk has separate own flv header and what those timestamps look like. Basically if chunk-1 ends at timestamp of 6 secs then chunk-2 cannot have first frame with timestamp of zero. In such a case you have to remove the flv header of chunk-2 & edit the timestamp in each frame to increase from 6 secs upwards. Does your coding language handle bytes editing? Or else try ffmpeg's `genpts` command?

Comment: Definitely i'm using a command incorrectly, since the output is corrupted. I used the concat command on a txt file containing the list of the flv chunks `ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy video.flv`. I tried the +genpts command but it gave me an error. Also I was looking with different flv players and encountered different behaviours with chunks after and included the number 2. VLC had some lag issues, Avidemux shows the video to the final 6 seconds of the total duration (so the first timestamp is not zero). Moyea shows a delayed video but audio starts at 0:00 of the chunk.

Comment: I'm going to link you the first two chunks [chunk0](http://uhs-akamai.ustream.tv/sjc/live/vod/sjc-2-ba4a399a-3335-405a-a31f-922190bfe466/3974680080000/47411666568000/plain/improved/1/chunk_0_a76bff6d39.flv) [chunk1](http://uhs-akamai.ustream.tv/sjc/live/vod/sjc-2-ba4a399a-3335-405a-a31f-922190bfe466/3974680080000/47411666568000/plain/improved/1/chunk_1_a76bff6d39.flv). I saw that Avidemux could be useful on trimming the flv files but it cuts portions of frames being not successful on creating even 12 seconds of a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the FLV chunks. The timestamps are **actually fine**.

**Short version :** 
Chunk-1 has an unnecessary FLV header. Remove it and paste the data at end of Chunk-0. Do it by some Hex Editor tool or write a basic utility to auto-fix each file in your coding language (PHP? Java? C++? You did not tag in your Question).

To avoid code, then using only FFmpeg, try extracting the video and the audio parts contained inside each FLV chunk. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i chunk1.flv -c:v copy chunk1.h264 //to get video 
ffmpeg -i chunk1.flv -c:a copy chunk1.aac //to get audio
```

- Merge the separate video files (h264) into one big h264 video file.
- Merge the separate audio files (aac) into one big AAC audio file.
- Join the video file & audio file as one inside either FLV or MP4 container.

**Long version :**

The problem is that both chunks **each** have an FLV header (first 13 bytes in each file). 
Only Chunk-0 needs a header, because Chunk-1 is a just continuation of the video where it gives next 6 seconds of FLV file.

To visualise your issue, let's look at the insides of your FLVs. As shown, after deleting extra bytes, you can just **paste** the remaining Chunk-1 bytes at the end of Chunk-0 and then re-save for a [**working FLV**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxxqewu61sjmo3d/chunks_VC_bytesPaste.flv?dl=1) file.

[image]

So just use your programming language to code a utility with simple logic :

> For each ascending chunk number that is not Chunk-0, delete its first 13
>   bytes and paste remaining at the end of Chunk-0.flv. 
> Repeat with each chunk until you have a large Chunk-0 FLV file of full duration.

As a test you can manually edit the chunks together by using a free hex editor software. On Windows I use [**HxD**](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php). Above images are grabbed from it.

- Open both chunks in the hex editor
- On Chunk-1 just **select** (highlight) & **delete** the first 13 bytes of FLV header (range 0 to 12). The header begins with a `46` at slot 0, and ends with an `00` at slot 12.
- The next bytes begin with `09` (video frame). It looks like `09 00 25 FF 00 17 etc etc`
- You want Chunk-1 to begin with above bytes instead of current `46 4C 56 01 etc etc`
- Finally... just ("Select All" and) **cut** all the Chunk-1 bytes and **paste** those bytes at the end of Chunk-0. **Save** as new FLV and try to play. It will work!!

This is the result [**working FLV**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxxqewu61sjmo3d/chunks_VC_bytesPaste.flv?dl=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was about finding what was the weird behaviour of the flv files; and that was the "unnecessity" of 13 bytes of the header. So: your link doesn't work but i was able to reproduce the process and obtaining what i believe is the same file. I may not use the audio-video extraction since it may (or may not, i'm not really an expert) decrease the quality. Since I remember i merged different flv files from another site/video with the concat command I thought there was something similar, but since you have to copy all bytes into a single file I may do it as you told